# How to make a drop-down in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want a drop-down to list all my categories, but when I click its links, browser does not react.

Here's my code

```
<select>
  <option>Select Category You Like</option>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
        <option>
          <%= link_to category.category, category %>
        </option>
    <% end %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the drop-down with CSS or JS and not with `select option` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn">
        Find Category You Like <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <% @categories.each do |category| %>
            <li class="">
                <span class="center"> <br>
                    <%= link_to category.category, category %> <small>(<%= category.blogs.count %>)</small>
                </span>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Its worked.. thanks